# Getting "undefined" while I try to access a state variable through useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-context

[This the error shown via parcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3h7p.png)I have created a context named `CardContext` and in another file `CardProvider` I am providing a state variable "card". I have imported `CardContext` in a component called `Social`. Through `useContext` I want to display the state variable "card" and expecting a value of "12". However, I am getting `undefined`. Can anyone please help me?

P.S:  Surprisingly enough I have written the exact same code(variable's name changed) to create SearchContext and SearchProvider and it is working.

I have included the code below

CardContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const CardContext = createContext();
```

CardProvider.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CardContext } from "./CardContext";

const CardProvider = (props) => {
  const [card, setCard] = useState("12");
  return (
    <CardContext.Provider value={[card, setCard]}>
      {props.children}
    </CardContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CardProvider;
```

Social.js

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { SearchContext } from '../context/SearchContext';
import { CardContext } from '../components/context2/CardContext';
const Social = () => {
  const card = useContext(CardContext);
  const [searchWord, setSearchWord] = useContext(SearchContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{"This is Social Page " + card}</h1>
      <h1>{"This is Social Page " + searchWord}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Social;
```

Initially, there were two other files( SearchContext and SearchProvider) in the context folder alongside CardContext and CardProvider. I created another folder called context2 and moved CardContext and CardProvider inside. It didn't work.

It was only being displayed if I explicitly gave a value inside the parenthesis of createContext(). However, I can't access [card, setCard] both in Social.js as the error would be undefined is not iterable(cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: Looks like `Social` is outside your `CardProvider`, or you forgot to wrap `CardProvider` around `Social`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message from your browser console.

Comment: Where are `CardProvider` and `Social` components rendered? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are providing the value to context as an array, and then you forgot it is an array when you try to use the value. It is not a good idea to provide values as array.

use below code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CardContext } from "./CardContext";

const CardProvider = (props) => {
  const [card, setCard] = useState("12");
 // change [card, setCard] to {card, setCard} 
  return (
    <CardContext.Provider value={{card, setCard}}> 
      {props.children}
    </CardContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CardProvider;
```

and then when you want to use it:

```
const card = useContext(CardContext).card;
// or
const { card } = useContext(CardContext)
```

I cannot see it in your code, but your Social component must be wrapped with CardProvider.

```
<CardProvider>
   <Social />
</CardProvider>
```

Comment: why is it not a good idea to provide values as an array?

Comment: @nullptr: because when you try to get the data back, lets say you want the second and third item in the array, you need to get the first one to, and if the first one change, you the component rerenders and that causes performance issues, also destructuring objects are a lor easier and if you use typescript, it gives you hints,